# How do semaphores provide mutual exclusion?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, synchronization, mutex, semaphore

I am having difficulty understanding how semaphores provide mutual exclusion when the value of the semaphore is larger than one.

Suppose the value of the semaphore is initially set to two.
Consider the following two threads which use the same semaphore s:

```
# Thread 1
wait(s) 
critical section
signal(s)

# Thread 2
wait(s)
critical section
signal(s)
```

In the following case (and possibly more cases), no mutual exclusion is provided:

```
1. Thread 1 is executing, it calls wait(s) and the value of s is decremented to one.
2. There is a context switch, Thread 2 is executing, it calls wait(s) and the value of s is now 0
3. Neither Thread 1 or Thread 2 are suspended since s>0 in both cases.
4. If any context switch happens from now on, both the threads will be executing their critical section
Doesn't this violate the principle of mutual exclusion?
```

Comment: Semaphores *don't* provide mutual exclusion when their initial value is greater than one.

Comment: In other words, semaphores can be used to limit the number of concurrent executions to a given max. number. The special case is when the maximum is set to `1`, and in that special case, they do provide mutual exclusion.

Comment: Thought that would be the case. The text I am reading confused me since it simply stated: "Semaphores can ensure mutual exclusion for any number of processes". Thanks for clearing it up.

Comment: That should more clearly say "any number of processes can be waiting on a single semaphore".

Answer (score 0):

Counting semaphore doesn't provide mutual exclusion. In counting semaphore, Mutual exclusion was not provided because we has the set of processes which required to execute in the critical section simultaneously.